# How to get the real envelope ID after offline signing

Tags: docusignapi

We're creating a iOS app and integrate with Docusign. We are using offline-signing to create an envelope and sign it. It returns a temporary envelope ID. After the offline signed envelope is synced to Docusign, it has a new envelope ID in Docusign. How can we retrieve that new ID from the app?

```
        mDSMEnvelopesManager?.composeEnvelope(with: envelope, signingMode: .offline, completion: { envelopeId, error in
            
            if let id = envelopeId {
                // offline
                self.mDSMEnvelopesManager?.resumeSigningEnvelope(withPresenting: presentingController, envelopeId: id, completion: { _, _ in })
            } else {
                // online
                self.showAlert(presentingController: presentingController, message: error.localizedDescription)
            }
        })
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! ***Please accept (check) the best answer to your question. Thank you!***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is that you store a unique value as envelope meta data using the [envelope custom field](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopecustomfields) feature.

Later, you can search on that field to find the right envelope.

Comment: Thanks, Larry. It's strange that we docusign doens't return the real envelope ID after syncing. We will try your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Actually Docusign does return the envelope ID after syncing. Just need to handle the

```
@objc func handleDSMEnvelopeSyncingSucceeded(notification: Notification) {
    //this is the real envelop ID need to send to backend
    self.envelopeID = notification.userInfo?["envelopeId"] as! String

}
```